# terraform cloud - planed but shows no options to apply

Tags: terraform

my workspace has connected to gitlab and it can be auto-planned with new commits made to gitlab.

but in "general settings" > "apply method", if i choose "auto", it will not apply automatically.
and if i choose "manual", even after it is successfully planned, it shows no options for me to "confirm & apply".

i have googled / searched inside https://learn.hashicorp.com and still cannot find related info in this.

any hints please ? what am i missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

support from terraform cloud is very helpful and provided this snippet to test with :

```
resource "null_resource" "null" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = timestamp()
  }
}
```

it turns out that if there's no ( so-called ) physical resources changes, the plan won't be able to apply, i've made some output changes to it and have therefore be neglected.  by adding this null resource, the auto apply performed as expected.